# Как спарсить первую картинку с загруженной страницы?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

- как правильно составить url запроса для поиска в google ?
- как спарсить первую картинку из ответа ?
- и где моя ошибка ?
  [image: код на картинке]

Answer (score 0):

Провел небольшое расследование. К заявленным тегам отношения конечно не имеет, но задачу я решил бы следующим образом.

1. Воспользуемся ссылкой  -

   https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&hl=ru&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=935&ei=yRAgWvD8I-SP6ASd1YsI&q=russia
2. Возьмем в качестве слова для запроса - `Russia` - будем приписывать в самом конце
3. Получим (скачаем) страницу -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Извлекаем из кода страницы ссылки вида (нам, к примеру, нужна первая) -

   https://www.google.ru/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F7%2F7d%2FMap_of_federal_subjects_of_Russia_%25282014%2529.svg%2F600px-Map_of_federal_subjects_of_Russia_%25282014%2529.svg.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRussia&docid=mfXGovdbdkbfSM&tbnid=3jNUwOHcizThGM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjJjKiEvebXAhVIQJoKHRZXALkQMwg7KAAwAA..i&w=600&h=349&hl=ru&bih=935&biw=1920&q=russia&ved=0ahUKEwjJjKiEvebXAhVIQJoKHRZXALkQMwg7KAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8
5. Переходим по этой ссылке и получаем (скачаем) страницу следующего вида -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6. Извлекаем из кода ссылку c окончанием формата изображения -

   https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Map_of_federal_subjects_of_Russia_%282014%29.svg/600px-Map_of_federal_subjects_of_Russia_%282014%29.svg.png

Она часть ссылки на 4 шаге. Там её можно отсечь, вернуть слеши и другие специальные знаки, например, заменой `%2F` на  `/`.

Извлекать ссылки можно с помощью регулярок или специальными на то программами, например `TextPipe`.